# Не нахожу /etc/pip.conf

Tags: linux, pip, redhat

Рабочая инструкция начинается с необходимости править файл /etc/pip.conf для подключения репозитория. Но такого файла на моём образе red hat, который я поставил на virtual box я не нашел. Требует ли появление этого файла установки чего-либо (того же питона) или он невидим в стандартном режиме, или... какие-то другие причины?

Comment: Почти не имел дел ни с линуксовыми системами, ни с питоном, поэтому вопрос выглядит наивно, но необходимость возникла.

Comment: А пакет, настройки которого должны быть в этом файле, установлен ? К каким либо стандартным конфигам он не относится, так что скорее всего он от какого то пакета

Comment: про местоположение конфигурационных файлов скрипта pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file . p.s. репозиторий наверняка можно указать ещё и с помощью опции при вызове скрипта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

согласно [документации к скрипту *pip*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file):

- для локальной пользовательской конфигурации директивы надо помещать в файл `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` (хотя читается и «старый» `~/.pip/pip.conf`)
- для глобальных директив можно использовать либо `/etc/pip.conf`, либо `/etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf`

насколько вижу, ни один из двух «глобальных» файлов (про «пользовательские» и речи быть не может) не входит ни в один пакет в популярных дистрибутивах операционной системы *gnu/linux*. т.е., «ждать их появления» не стоит. создайте сами и впишите нужные директивы.